# How to get Helmet to insert title and meta data when using SSR

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-helmet

I'm trying to setup Helmet npm using SSR within my meteor application and I'm not sure what I need to do to get page title and metadata to appear on my homepage. There are no errors, however, I'm new to using SSR so I'm not following what I'm missing here. Very nooooob question.

Path: `server/main.js`

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { onPageLoad } from "meteor/server-render";
import { renderToNodeStream } from "react-dom/server";
import { ServerStyleSheet } from "styled-components"
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';  

import App from "/imports/server/app/App";

onPageLoad(sink => {
  const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
  const appJSX = sheet.collectStyles(
    <App location={sink.request.url} />
  );

  App.propTypes = {
    location: PropTypes.object,
  };


  const htmlStream = sheet.interleaveWithNodeStream(
    renderToNodeStream(appJSX)
    );

  sink.renderIntoElementById("react-root-app", htmlStream);

  const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();
  sink.appendToHead(helmet.meta.toString());
  sink.appendToHead(helmet.title.toString());

});
```

Path: `client/hompage.jsx`

```
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <Helmet>
        <title>Homepage</title>
        <meta name="description" content="This is homepage. Just Helmet SSR demo" />
        <meta property="og:title" content="This is homepage. Just Helmet SSR demo for OG" />
      </Helmet>
    <h1>Home</h1>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: helmet code looks fine. The issue might be with onPageLoad from meteor